# ContentView doesn't show up when working with FadeTo in android

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a custom view with these properties set inside the ContentView tag:

```xml
Opacity="0"
InputTransparent="True"
IsVisible="false"
BackgroundColor="Transparent"
```

And this behind code to show the ContentView.

```cs
// This would be the point where the animation begins and the point where it ends.
readonly double yPosOrigin = 30;
readonly double yPosOpen = 0;
readonly uint animationSpeed = 150;

new public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public FoodFullView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TranslationY = -yPosOrigin;
}

private async void OpenAnimation()
{
    IsVisible = true;

    await Task.WhenAll(
        this.FadeTo(1, length: animationSpeed),
        this.TranslateTo(0, yPosOpen, length: animationSpeed, easing: Easing.SinIn));
    
    RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
    InputTransparent = false;
}

private async void CloseAnimation()
{
    InputTransparent = true;

    await Task.WhenAll(
        this.FadeTo(0, length: animationSpeed),
        this.TranslateTo(0, -yPosOrigin, length: animationSpeed, easing: Easing.SinIn));

    IsVisible = false;
    RaiseOnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
    
    NumberChose.Quantity = 1;
    BindingContext = null;
}
```

The problem is that when running this on Android, the custom view doesn't show up, however,
running this on windows doesn't have any problems, the content view shows up as usual.

Is there something that I have to do when working with Android with this kind of stuff?

Comment: Trying to run the async code on MainThread, if that does not work this is probably a bug.

Comment: Doesn't work, another thing is that if you set the IsVisible and the Opacity to True and 1 first, than the CloseAnimation() and the OpenAnimation() will work

Comment: Did you tested it on the ios? It appears to be a bug.

Comment: No I don't have ios license nor mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed on .Net8 now